# "Line in" source not recognized in 16.04

Tags: sound, source

"Line in" source won't play through to headphone output though it worked in Windows on the same machine when in dual boot. ALSAmixer shows LINE but no volume slider on the Capture page (F4) in Terminal. Pulse Audio "Line in (plugged in)" and unmuted.

Comment: "Line In" is input, not output.

Comment: I didn't say it was. I'm seeking a headphone output from a signal source connected to the line in input.